# Vue: Invalid prop: type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios, vue-component

When I fetch data from my backend service I get multiple warnings in Vue saying:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "item". Expected Item, got Object
```

I further have the following code:

**ItemCard**

```html
<template>
...
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from "vue-class-component";
import { Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { Item } from "./Item";

export default class ItemCard extends Vue { 
  @Prop(Item) item!: Item;
}
</script>
```

**Menu**

```html
<template>
        <div v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id" class="category-wrapper">
          <h2 class="title dm-text-header">{{ category.title }}</h2>
          <h4 class="subheading ">{{ category.description }}</h4>

          <ItemCard
            v-for="item in category.items" 
            :key="item.id"
            v-bind:item="item"
          >
          </ItemCard>
        </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Restaurant } from "./Restaurant"; 

@Options({
  components: {
    ItemCard
  }
})
export default class Menu extends Vue {
  ...
  restaurant: Restaurant | null = null;
  categories: Category[] = [];
  ...

  getRestaurant(): void {
    axios.get<Restaurant>(this.restaurantUrl)
    .then(res => {
      this.restaurant = res.data;
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
// Restaurant
import { Menu } from './Menu';
export class Restaurant {
    menu!: Menu;
}

// Menu 
import { Category } from './Category';
export class Menu {
    categories!: Category[];
}

// Category
import { Item } from './Item';
export class Category {
    items!: Item[];
}

// Item
export class Item{
   ...
}
```

`axios` is always returning the the result(`Restaurant`) as type `object` instead of the `Resturant` type I want it to have. I can access the categories/items over the `Restaurant`, but these are as well already of type `object` instead of the expected type (`Category/Item`).

The code works fine insofar that everything is displayed, but a lot of warnings are shown, so I think I'm doing something wrong. Where and what would I need to change to fix these warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Object as PropType<Item>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Annotating-Props):

```js
import { PropType } from 'vue';

export default class ItemCard extends Vue {
  @Prop(Object as PropType<Item>) item!: Item;
}
```